# How to match and count by names in a data frame for each name grouped?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with Species names plus V1, V4 or V9 (or just the species name) on a column, and I have a column with many Order names which repeat along side the column.
What I need is something that helps me count the number of times it matches V1 of the first column with every order, and then the same for V4 and V9.

I've tried this for the V1 count:

```
countordens <- malardf %>%
  group_by(ordens) %>%
  summarise(V1=(sum(str_count(malardf$malar_names, pattern="V1"))))
```

But it returns a column with orders grouped, but with the total amount of V1 on the dataframe, instead of the total amount of V1 for each Order.

```
                 malar_names malaordens.Order
1  Protomima imitatrix V1 V9        Amphipoda
2 Caprella danilevskii V1 V9        Amphipoda
3           Caprella andreae        Amphipoda
4           Caprella andreae        Amphipoda
5           Caprella andreae        Amphipoda
6           Caprella andreae        Amphipoda
```

I'm hoping to get a dataframe with each order from Orders only once, and a second column with the amount of times it matches that order with "V1" on the dataframe, and another for "V4" and another for "V9".

Comment: Replace the `malardf$malar_names`, `malardf$ordens` with `malar_names`, `orderns`.  Also, noticed that `str_count` is not closed brackets and it doesn't returns a logical value

Comment: sorry, the first code didn't return the data frame I stated, I corrected the code so it does now

Comment: IYou may need to remove `malardf$` because it is going to extracting all the values from the column instead of the values within the group i.e. `malardf %>%
  group_by(ordens) %>%
  summarise(V1=(sum(str_count(malar_names, pattern="V1"))))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we want to get the counts of multiple values, then use `map`

```
library(tidyverse)
map(c("V1", "V4", "V9"), ~ 
                         malardf %>%
                               group_by(malaordens.Order) %>%
                               summarise(!! .x := sum(str_count(malar_names,
                                pattern = .x)))) %>%
   reduce(inner_join, by = "malaordens.Order") 
# A tibble: 1 x 4
#  malaordens.Order    V1    V4    V9
#  <chr>            <int> <int> <int>
#1 Amphipoda            2     0     2
```

---

Note that the OP's issue in the code while counting a single pattern also stems from extracting whole column (`malardf$`) after doing the `group_by`.  Within in `mutate/summarise`, there is no need to use `data$`, instead just pass the unquoted column name.  It would work invariably with or without group by operation

#### data

```
malardf <- structure(list(malar_names = c("Protomima imitatrix V1 V9",
 "Caprella danilevskii V1 V9", 
"Caprella andreae", "Caprella andreae", "Caprella andreae", "Caprella andreae"
), malaordens.Order = c("Amphipoda", "Amphipoda", "Amphipoda", 
"Amphipoda", "Amphipoda", "Amphipoda")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I got this error:
Error: Argument 2 must be length 563, not 10

Comment: @tadeufontes  I changed the code slightly, not sure if it was the previouss one you tried.  This should work